What is the logic behind view reading from invoker-enabled view
I'm trying to understand the role switching in PostgreSQL when I'm selecting a regular view which is directly reading from a view with the security_invoker=true option enabled.
I expect the following behaviour:

regular view = run "prepared query" under owner's permissions
view with security_invoker = run "prepared query" under caller's permissions

I now have these two scenarios:

A view with security_invoker (A) is performing a SELECT over a regular view (B). The result is that the caller sees the content as owner of the view (B). This is understandable.
A regular view (C) is performing a SELECT over a view with security_invoker (D). The result is that the caller sees the content as him/herself. Not the owner.

This is a bit strange, since I would expect the the role to be "set" to the C-view owner on select and then carry this role when performing the select on the underlying view. My code example shows this using RLS but Postgres acts the same if I just revoke SELECT on the underlying table.
Thanks for any clarification on the logic behind this. Here is code to replicate my tests:
demo at db<>fiddle
CREATE SCHEMA test_views;

SET search_path TO test_views;

CREATE ROLE emplo;
CREATE ROLE manager;
GRANT usage ON SCHEMA test_views TO emplo, manager;
GRANT CREATE ON SCHEMA test_views TO manager;

CREATE TABLE test_views.employees (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(100),
    department VARCHAR(100),
    salary NUMERIC
);

INSERT INTO test_views.employees (name, department, salary)
SELECT 
    'Employee ' || (RANDOM() * 100) :: INT,
    CASE
        WHEN RANDOM() < 0.5 THEN 'IT'
        ELSE 'HR'
    END,
    (RANDOM() * 100000) :: NUMERIC
FROM
    generate_series(1, 1000);


ALTER TABLE test_views.employees ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;

CREATE POLICY emplo_hr_policy ON test_views.employees 
FOR
SELECT
USING (department = 'HR');

CREATE POLICY manager_all_policy ON test_views.employees 
FOR SELECT 
TO manager 
USING (TRUE);

GRANT INSERT ON test_views.employees TO manager;
GRANT SELECT ON test_views.employees TO emplo, manager;
GRANT usage ON SEQUENCE test_views."employees_id_seq" TO manager;
SET ROLE TO manager;

-- Creating a view with security invoker
CREATE
OR REPLACE VIEW test_views.invoker_view WITH (security_invoker = TRUE) AS
SELECT *
FROM employees;

-- Creating a normal view that reads from the invoker_view
CREATE
OR REPLACE VIEW test_views.leader_view AS
SELECT *
FROM invoker_view;

CREATE
OR REPLACE VIEW test_views.normal_view AS
SELECT *
FROM employees;

-- Creating a view with security invoker that reads from the normal_view
CREATE
OR REPLACE VIEW test_views.invoker_view_2 WITH (security_invoker = TRUE) AS
SELECT *
FROM normal_view;

GRANT SELECT ON 
    test_views.invoker_view,
    test_views.leader_view,
    test_views.normal_view,
    test_views.invoker_view_2 
TO emplo, manager;


Test selects:
select current_role;
set role to emplo;

select * from test_views.invoker_view; -- invoker, see as caller
select * from test_views.leader_view; -- regular reads from invoker, <explain?>
select * from test_views.normal_view; -- regular, see as owne
select * from test_views.invoker_view_2; -- invoker reads from regular, see as the regular view owner 

